# Foliopress WYSIWYG editor does not display images

Tags: editor, wysiwyg, images

I use the [Foliopress WYSIWYG editor](http://foliovision.com/seo-tools/wordpress/plugins). I inserted overview-1.png via the 'Quick Insert Image' option. This added the following mark-up:

```
<img width="166" height="263" alt="overview 1" src="images/2012/01/overview-1.png" />
```

The width and height attributes are correct yet the editor can't find the src. But on the FE the img gets displayed.

How do I display the img in the WYSIWYG as well?

Comment: Could you verify that it does in fact not find the src using a tool such as Firebug? In all likelihood it will be because almost everything in WordPress requires absolute addresses, and relative ones will mostly fail due to the complex system of redirects and rewrites.

Comment: Yes, I can verify that. I probably would use absolute paths, but foliopress is using relative ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A base-Element in the front-end's header was the reason, why it worked in the fe but not in the editor.